# initialize GAE datastore with start data?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

this is my first question on stackoverflow and I'm new to programming:

What is the right way to load data into the GAE datastore when deploying my app? This should only happen once at deployment.

In other words: How can I call methods in my code, such that these methods are only called when I deploy my app?

The GAE documentation for python2.7 says, that one shouldn't call a main function, so I can't do this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   initialize_datastore()
   main()
```

Comment: you could just check to see if data exists and if not, run your startup scripts

Comment: Yeah, don't do that. In fact, if you have the "if __name__ == '__main__'" code at the bottom of your handler script at all, remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a handler that is restricted to admins only. When that handler is invoked with a simple GET request you could have it check to see if the seed data exists and if it doesn't, insert it.

[Configuring a handler to require login or administrator status.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status)

Another option is to write a Python script that utilizes the Remote API. This would allow you to access local data sources such as a CSV file or a locally hosted database and wouldn't require you to create a potentially unwieldy handler.

Read about the Remote API in the docs.

[Using the Remote API Shell  - Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi#Running_Remote_Shell)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This sounds like not so elegant workaround. Is this such a special problem? There should be an easy way, or not?

Comment: What @Timbatron suggests is elegant, and the correct way to do it. If you have a lot of data to create you might consider running it in a taskqueue (which has a 10 minute deadline instead of 1)

Comment: Well how about the Remote API then? Totally blanked on that option while I was responding at first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will play with both options and then decide, what's the best for me.